# onPaymentSuccess and onPaymentError probably not implemented in your activity - Xamarin Android - Razorpay Integration

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, razorpay

I am implementing the RazorPay payment gateway from my Xamarin Android App. Problem is that when I make the payment callback function onPaymentSuccess and onPaymentError is not invoked. I am sharing my code, please go through it and let me know what are the changes required?

```
  public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            Checkout checkOut = new Checkout();
            checkOut.SetKeyID("********");
            AppCompatActivity activity = this;
            try
            {
                JSONObject jsonoptions = new JSONObject();
                jsonoptions.Put("description", "My Sample Payment activity");
                jsonoptions.Put("order_id", orderId);
                jsonoptions.Put("currency", "INR");
                jsonoptions.Put("amount", _amount);
                checkOut.Open(activity, jsonoptions);
            }
            catch (ExceptionInInitializerError ex)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("error in payment");
            }   
         }


        public void onPaymentError(int p0, string p1, PaymentData p2)
        {
            string paymentid = p2.PaymentId;
            string orderid = p2.OrderId;

        }
        public void onPaymentSuccess(string p0, PaymentData p1)
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: working with RazorPay Testing Key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current Activity should derives from interface `IPaymentResultWithDataListener`, then the two methods would invoke after that .

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity , IPaymentResultWithDataListener
```